# Error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array after apache upgrade

Tags: php, arrays, apache, scalar

They just upgraded my server to a new version of Apache 2.2.27. It messed up a few things, and I now have an error report where all was fine before:

> Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /var/www/vhosts/madcaplogic.com/httpdocs/login/teacher/dispatch.php on line 55

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I've been told that this may repeat farther down the code, so insight on that would also be helpful.

Here's the relevant code for that error:

```
// Perform URL redirection (this preserves all GET, POST and COOKIE variables without need for resubmitting forms/posts)
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) ) {
    unset($_SESSION['header_vars']);
} else if ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['sd'] ) ) || ( isset( $_SESSION['sd'] ) ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['sd'] = true;
        // Enable error reporting
        ini_set('display_errors',1); 
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['sd']);
    }
} else if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ) {
    $session_id = uniqid( "", true );
    $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ] = array();
    $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['time'] = microtime( true );
    foreach ( $_REQUEST as $session_key => $session_val ) {
        $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ][ $session_key ] = $session_val;
    }
    $_SESSION['file_vars'][ $session_id ] = array();
    $_SESSION['file_vars'][ $session_id ]['time'] = $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['time'];
    foreach ( $_FILES as $session_key => $session_val ) {
        $_SESSION['file_vars'][ $session_id ][ $session_key ] = $session_val;
        $_SESSION['file_vars'][ $session_id ][ 'content' ] = file_get_contents( $_FILES[ $session_key ]['tmp_name'][0] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['msg'] ) ) $msg = $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['msg'] = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['err'] ) ) $err = $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['err'] = $_REQUEST['err'];
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['msg'] ) ) $msg = $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['msg'] = $_SESSION['msg'];
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['err'] ) ) $err = $_SESSION['header_vars'][ $session_id ]['err'] = $_SESSION['err'];
    header( 'location:/login/teacher/dispatch.php?s=' . $session_id );
    exit();
} else {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['header_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_SESSION['header_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']] as $session_key => $session_val ) {
            if ( !isset( $_REQUEST[$session_key] ) ) {
                $_REQUEST[$session_key] = $session_val;
                /*if ( "debug" == $session_key ) {
                    unset( $_SESSION['header_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']]['debug'] );
                }*/
            }
        }
        foreach ( $_SESSION['file_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']] as $session_key => $session_val ) {
            if ( !isset( $_FILES[$session_key] ) ) {
                $_FILES[$session_key] = $session_val;
                $_FILES[$session_key]['content'] = $_SESSION['file_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']]['content'];
            }
        }
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['msg'] ) ) $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['err'] ) ) $err = $_REQUEST['err'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you pointed out where line 55 is, and what the `var_dump()` of whatever values are being used there are.

Comment: as @MarcB pointed out we need the relevant line as the code provided only adds up to 51!

Comment: Sorry about that! I tried to edit the post to include the very top lines, but to no avail.Here's line 55, to my best count:$_FILES[$session_key]['content'] = $_SESSION['file_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']]['content'];

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['header_vars'][$_REQUEST['s']]);